# Extracting all keys from a JSON object unless a certain key has a value

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.4

My Postgres jsonb-foo isn't that great but I'd appreciate some help with a query I am trying to put together.

I have this rudimentary query to extract the name of all keys in the `_doc`'s 'answers' key. The jsonb data looks something like this

```
_doc = {
    "answers": {
        "baz": true,
        "qux": true
        "other": "How do i find this"
    }
}
```

and a query might look this this:

```sql
SELECT ss.foo, count(DISTINCT (ss.bar)) FROM (
      SELECT    (_doc::jsonb -> 'bar')::text as bar,
                jsonb_object_keys(_doc::jsonb -> 'answers' -> 'foo') as foo
      FROM public."table_name"
  ) ss
WHERE ss.foo IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ss.foo;
```

So really the output here would be the number of times each key of `answers` appears.

`("baz" = 1, "qux" = 1, "other" = 1)`

Here is my problem, I want to get the number of times each key appears, apart from in the case of `other`. In that case I want to get the number of times its contents appears. So I want the result to be

`("baz" = 1, "qux" = 1, "How do i find this" = 1)`

If possible I would love some help structuring this query.

Thank you

Comment: So it is possible to have one key twice?

Comment: Sorry @S-Man could you clarify? Each row's `_doc` can absolutely have the same data, the the total count would be `("baz" = 2, "qux" = 2, "How do i find this" = 2)` where `_doc` is a valid `jsonb` type

Comment: Do you have certain json records or does one answers object can contain twice the same "baz" or "other:foo" key?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1afab95812a4a664cbd67f1a866d0af5 for twice the same key

Comment: Perfect, yeh a duplicate key would never technically happen in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6b055fee720549ca31367e14f8b78368) for several json records
- [demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a3753a50c6bb0af4c51ecab12e1ea250) for one json records which has the same key twice (strictly not recommended!)

Using the `json_each_text()` function to get the key/value pairs. After that take the keys or the value of `other`, selecting through a `CASE` clause

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN elems.key = 'other' THEN elems.value
        ELSE elems.key
    END AS key,
    COUNT(*)
FROM data,
    json_each_text(jsondata -> 'answers') AS elems
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: This was an excellent answer by the way, thank you. I wouldn't have immediately thought to break the json down into tuples and then `case` on them